# First and last record for a user in a given time period in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to get the first and last record for a given `user_id` in a time period, for example, 24 hours.

I am aware this could be done using two queries, doing something like this and then switching the `ORDER BY` `ASC`/`DESC`.

```
SELECT id, user_id, date, other_columns
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 1 AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

However, I am wondering if it would be possible to do this using one query.

Comment: It is, but it will probably be faster with 2 queries. Use UNION or subquery if you need both in one result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that you could consider:

```
SELECT t.id, t.user_id, t.date, t.other_columns
FROM table t
WHERE user_id = 1
    AND date = (
        SELECT MIN(date)
        FROM table
        WHERE user_id = t.user_id
            AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
UNION ALL
SELECT id, user_id, date, other_columns
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 1
    AND date = (
        SELECT MAX(date)
        FROM table
        WHERE user_id = t.user_id
            AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting upvotes, considering that it does not do what OP is asking for - "I am looking to get the first and last record **for a given user_id** in a time period".